# Whether "group polarization" and "social segregation" is the same?

Tags: social-networks

In a paper of ([Murase, 2019](https://www.nature.com/articles/s41598-019-40990-z)) use both terms "group polarization" and "social segregation".

The "group polarization" is explained [here](https://psychology.stackexchange.com/questions/27815/what-is-the-name-of-phenomenon-that-people-state-their-initial-opinion-more-firm), and the author also documents about the "social segregation" as

> The relationship between homophily and segregation has been recognized
> long ago.(...)In another approach to social segregation, opinion
> dynamics is used so that similar people can influence each other

I am wondering whether these two terms "**group polarization**" and "**social segregation**" are the same?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Social segregation and group polarization are different concepts.

Social segregation, (i.e. racial segregation, residential segregation, sex segregation) is defined as "[the separation or isolation of people or other entities so that there is a minimum of interaction between them](https://dictionary.apa.org/segregation)"

Group polarization refers to when an individual's attitude or opinion changes after the influence of a group, to be more extreme (or polarized) than prior to being exposed to the group [(Sieber & Ziegler, 2019)](https://journals.sagepub.com/doi/full/10.1177/0146167219833389).

**References**

Sieber, J., & Ziegler, R. (2019). Group Polarization Revisited: A Processing Effort Account. Personality and Social Psychology Bulletin, 45(10), 1482–1498. https://doi.org/10.1177/0146167219833389

APA Dictionary of Psychology: https://dictionary.apa.org/segregation